# How to review my latest flag and change if pending?

Tags: support

I have various pending flags in my account. I can see the list of the flags by clicking number against helpful flag field, that takes me to a list of question I flagged and stated reason along with status of the flag.

Now if I want to change the flag or remove the old flag, is it possible to do?

If I can not do anything to the old flags then; when one is in ban from flagging, what is the significance of the message at the bottom of the screen asking to review your past flags? **We should be either allowed to edit the flags or this message should be modified** to a simple statement that **you are banned from flagging for these many days**

[image: Too many recent flags decined]

Comment: No, you cannot retract or change flags once cast.